# NetDataContractSerializer equivalent for Silverlight?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, web-services, serialization

Has anyone developed or know of a place where I could find a Silverlight implementation of NetDataContractSerializer?

This [WCF and Silverlight Comparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc896571(VS.95).aspx) states that Silverlight does not ship with an implementation of NetDataContractSerializer.

I'm hoping to avoid developing one myself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I think the Silverlight version of CSLA includes some form of binary [serializer](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/SilverlightSerializer.aspx).  It's not compatible with NetDataContractSerializer I think, so you'll need to use it on both the server and client (CSLA comes in a Windows flavour too).  You can get the full framework (with source) for free at http://www.lhotka.net/cslalight/